# Extract vertices from dbgeometry value

Tags: c#, well-known-text

Who knows the elegant way to extract coordinates of polygon vertices from well known text representation of DbGeometry value?

Here's my polygon for example:

```
 {POLYGON ((52.808019 -1.345367, 53.095124 -1.345367, 53.095124 -0.864716, 52.808019 -0.864716, 52.808019 -1.345367))}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my elegant solution :)

```
 double x1 = dbGeometry.PointAt(1).XCoordinate.Value;
 double x2 = dbGeometry.PointAt(2).XCoordinate.Value;
 double x3 = dbGeometry.PointAt(3).XCoordinate.Value;
 double x4 = dbGeometry.PointAt(4).XCoordinate.Value;
 double y1 = dbGeometry.PointAt(1).YCoordinate.Value;
 double y2 = dbGeometry.PointAt(2).YCoordinate.Value;
 double y3 = dbGeometry.PointAt(3).YCoordinate.Value;
 double y4 = dbGeometry.PointAt(4).YCoordinate.Value;
```